# c# mvc and EF - valid model returns as invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a form which I want to submit and save the data using EF, but even if all the fields are filled out correctly upon submission it still enters the `invalid` conditional. I think it has something to do with `Id` column which it shows as `0` when other fields are filled out.

Pages Data Model:

```
public class PagesVM
{

    public PagesVM()
    {
    }

    public PagesVM(PagesDTO pagesDTO)
    {
        Id = pagesDTO.Id;
        Title = pagesDTO.Title;
        Slug = pagesDTO.Slug;
        Body = pagesDTO.Body;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Post action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("add-page")]
public ActionResult AddPage(PagesVM pagesVM)
{
    if (! ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("AddPage", pagesVM);
    }

    using (Db db = new Db())
    {
        PagesDTO pagesDTO = new PagesDTO();
        pagesDTO.Title = pagesVM.Title;
        pagesDTO.Slug = pagesVM.Slug;
        pagesDTO.Body = pagesVM.Body;

        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    ViewBag.SM = "You have added a new page!";

    return View("AddPage");
}
```

So regardless if the form is filled out properly it goes into `if (! ModelState.IsValid)` always.

Comment: Of course ! In your view, you have to generate an html editor for your ID and make it invisible... it sounds weird but beleive me, it's probably the most efficient way.

Comment: OK but what am I supposed to put for value? It's supposed to autoincrement in the db.

Comment: Wait, if it auto increment your not suposed to specify the primary key when adding

Comment: Exactly ,public int? Id {get;set;} is the real answer.

Comment: that ? can change a lot of things for entity, nullable types for auto-incrementing values ! i will remember that !

Comment: You do NOT need an input for `Id` and you do not need to make it nullable and it has absolutely nothing to do with why `ModelState` is invalid. (`0` is a valid value for `int`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Id is not set yet you would need to change

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

to

```
public int? Id {get;set;}
```

for the model to accurately represent the data and pass validation.

If it is always set before this view and not coming through you need to put it in a

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
```

inside the form tags